# PayPal adaptive payments ipnNotificationUrl is not getting hit for app/facilitator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am creating the following pay request with the ruby adaptive payment sdk:

```
fee = 2
api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments.new
pay = api.build_pay({
    :actionType => "PAY",
    :cancelUrl => "https://localhost:3000/purchases/paypal_cancelled?purchase_guid=" + self.guid,
    :currencyCode => self.currency,
    :feesPayer => "PRIMARYRECEIVER",
    :ipnNotificationUrl => "http://paypal.corstiaan.ultrahook.com/purchases/paypal_ipn_notify?purchase_guid=" + self.guid,
    :receiverList => {
        :receiver => [{
            :amount => 20,
            :email => seller@email.com,
            :primary => true
            }, {
            :amount => fee,
            :email => 'ch-facilitator@corstiaan.com'
         }],
  },
  :returnUrl => "https://localhost:3000/purchases/paypal_success?purchase_guid=" + self.guid + "&verification_key=" + paypal_verification_key })
  pay_response = api.pay(pay)
```

Everything works just like I want it to. I am the facilitator of the transaction and secondary receiver and the seller is the primary receiver. This is all ok. Also, the cancel and return urls are being called correctly.

Only the ipnNotificationUrl is not getting hit. I have set up a forward using ultrahook.com which is getting called correctly when using paypal's ipn simulator (that does not support adaptive ipn messages for some reason...) so technically that forward should work, but I never see anything hitting my server...

I am lost in the paypal docs, which are terrible.

When I view the IPN history ch-facilitator@corstiaan.com I only see IPN messages that relate to the payment of the fee from the seller to facilitator, nothing regarding the whole transaction which should be posted to ipnNotificationUrl if I understand correctly up to this point.

What am I doing wrong/what can be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? Facing the same issue.

Comment: No, unfortunately. I moved forward without the ipn notification.